# MVC Multiple models and multiple view form

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What i want to accomplish is going from one form which is takes in basic detail of a donation, then going to a second form that will take all the necessary data for card payment and before entering all this data going to another page that will display all the information and allow them to edit before they click confirm that will save the data to the database.

Here is my donation model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace donation3.Models
{
    public class donation
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        private DateTime joined = DateTime.Now;
        [Display(Name = "Donation Date")]
        public DateTime DonationDate { get { return joined; } set { joined = value; } }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Amount")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
        [Range(2, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Donation must be greater than 2")]
        [RegularExpression("[0-9]{1,}", ErrorMessage = "Only whole pounds can be donated")]
        public decimal Amount { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Tax Bonus")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:c}")]
        public decimal TaxBonus { get { return Convert.ToDecimal(Amount / 100 * 22); } set { Convert.ToDecimal(Amount / 100 * 22); } }

        [Display(Name = "Comment")]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Comment { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my payment model

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace donation3.Models
{
    public class payment
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Name is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Name on card")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string NameOnCard { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Card number is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Card number")]
        public int CardNumber { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Valid from")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime ValidFrom { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Date is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Expires")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime Expires { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Issue Number is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Issue Number")]
        public int IssueNumber { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Security code is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Security code")]
        public int SecurityCode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Address is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Address")]
        [StringLength(200)]
        public string Address { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "City is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "City")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string City { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "State is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "State")]
        public string State { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Country is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Country")]
        [StringLength(100)]
        public string Country { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Postcode is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Postcode")]
        //[RegularExpression(@"(GIR 0AA)|((([A-Z-[QVX]][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z-[QVX]][A-Z-[IJZ]][0-9][0-9]?)|(([A-Z-[QVX]][0-9][A-HJKPSTUW])|([A-Z-[QVX]][A-Z-[IJZ]][0-9][ABEHMNPRVWXY])))) [0-9][A-Z-[CIKMOV]]{2})")]
        public string Postcode { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email is Required")]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}" +
                            @"\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\" +
                            @".)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$",
                            ErrorMessage = "Email is not valid")]
        public string Email { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is my donation controller

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using donation3.Models;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace donation3.Controllers
{
    public class donationsController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public donationsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;    
        }

        // GET: donations
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_context.donation.ToList());
        }

        //go to next form
        public IActionResult paymentDetails()
        {
            return View("/Views/payments/Create.cshtml");
        }


        // GET: donations/Details/5
        public IActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            donation donation = _context.donation.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            if (donation == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(donation);
        }

        // GET: donations/Create
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: donations/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(donation donation)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

               return RedirectToAction("paymentDetails");
            }
            return View(donation);
        }

        // GET: donations/Edit/5
        public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            donation donation = _context.donation.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            if (donation == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(donation);
        }

        // POST: donations/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Edit(donation donation)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Update(donation);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(donation);
        }

        // GET: donations/Delete/5
        [ActionName("Delete")]
        public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            donation donation = _context.donation.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            if (donation == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(donation);
        }

        // POST: donations/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            donation donation = _context.donation.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            _context.donation.Remove(donation);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }






    }
}
```

Here is my payment controller

```
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.Data.Entity;
using donation3.Models;

namespace donation3.Controllers
{
    public class paymentsController : Controller
    {

        private ApplicationDbContext _context;

        public paymentsController(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;    
        }



        // GET: payments
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(_context.payment.ToList());
        }

        // GET: payments/Details/5
        public IActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            payment payment = _context.payment.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            if (payment == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(payment);
        }

        // GET: payments/Create
        [HttpGet]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: payments/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Create(payment payment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.payment.Add(payment);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(payment);
        }

        // GET: payments/Edit/5
        public IActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            payment payment = _context.payment.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            if (payment == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(payment);
        }

        // POST: payments/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult Edit(payment payment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Update(payment);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(payment);
        }

        // GET: payments/Delete/5
        [ActionName("Delete")]
        public IActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            payment payment = _context.payment.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            if (payment == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            return View(payment);
        }

        // POST: payments/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public IActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            payment payment = _context.payment.Single(m => m.ID == id);
            _context.payment.Remove(payment);
            _context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how im going from one form to another

```
//go to next form
        public IActionResult paymentDetails()
        {
            return View("/Views/payments/Create.cshtml");
        }
```

So my questions are

1. How do i go from one form to another
2. How do i keep the data until the user confirms the creation
3. How do i create a new page displaying all entered detail with a confirm/ edit button

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please do not just dump all your code here (90% of which is irrelevant to your question) - no one is going to wade through all this. Refer [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Sorry, but im not sure what people would need to help :/

Comment: It looks like you're struggling with keeping the data somewhere. You can do the clean solution by sending viewmodels along, seperate models that contain the data the user needs. Some model that has a donation and a payment object inside? But it's also possible to store them in viewbag variables, temporary variables that need to be resetted each time you do a redirect.

Comment: @leuan Walker Please upvote if you find the answer satisfactory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi I am not going to write code for you because as a developer you need to learn how to find this yourself and its not that difficult so I am going to provide some guidance. Also I am not going to guarantee that these are the best methods but they will work

1.You can create a button tag and use Url.Action to set the href property for page navigation. You can also use the Html.Editor or Html.EditorFor and set its htmlattributes  for making it button.

2.You can keep the data in a Session object whose value you can assign from your model or view-model whatever you are using since I didn't read your whole code. You can keep data in a table that stores temporary data or use some other option.

3.You can create a view model for your final page setting whatever properties you want in your view model according to what you want to display in your view. When you go from your second page to your last page i.e the details page you will be calling an action method when you submit the button on your second page. Hence in that action method you will initialize your view model and pass it to the view for the details page.

I hope this answer satisfied you

Comment: Thank you, ill look into it now

Comment: If you find it satisfactory please upvote also